# How to migrate custom master pages from sharepoint 2010 to SP2016?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We are migrating from sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint 2016. Content DB migration is completed. Now need to migrate the custom solution. Can you please provide the best approach to migrate custom master page? Or do i need to re-build it again?

Answer (score 0):

Because the master page in SharePoint 2016 is completely different you have to create new master page (copy seattle.master for example) and apply your changes (CSS, HTML, placeholders...).